# Incorrect total averages showing in excel pivot tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table report, and in the Filter Field I have 3 options "All", "Indigenous People", and "non-Indigenous people".  If I select the Filter option to "Indigenous People" and put in the Totals field that I want it to give the average, it gives me the correct result.  Same for "non-Indigenous".  If I sum these two averages myself it gives me the correct result I want for the total average (i.e Total average=Indigenous average plus non-Indigenous average)

However, if I Filter to "All" and select that I want the average, it gives me an incorrect answer.  I don't understand why? What is it calculating if not Total average=Indigenous average plus non-Indigenous average?

Comment: The sum of two averages is not a “total average”.   If you really *really* (really?) want to add two averages, please find some other name for the sum than “total average”.

Answer (score 0):

The pivot table would be taking all the data and averaging it, So

```
 (indigenous sum + non indigenous sum) / (indigenous count + non indigenous count).
```

I would recommend a calculated field were it would be

```
 (indigenous sum / indigenous count ) + (non indigenous sum / non indigenous count)
```

This would show all the field in 3 separate columns, indigenous, non indigenous , and indigenous average + non indigenous average.